# using Regex and/or removing duplicate

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I am **scraping** the website and as a result, I have half cleaned code:

```
[3] "2♠2:2♠2: Texas:28,,845:25,46,5:4.4%:36♠36:55,32:9,23:698,53:8.68%"*
```

Above is one example and I am trying to remove a number before or after that heart.

**Desired output is:
[3] "2:2: Texas:28,,845:25,46,5:4.4%:36:55,32:9,23:698,53:8.68%"**

Basically removing numbers between heart and colon including heart.
I will greatly appreciate any help. I have tried the following codes, but they did not work.

```
str_replace_all(dataSet, "♠*:", "", fixed = T) 
gsub("*♠", "", data, fixed = T)


website <- read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_the_United_States_by_population")

results <- website %>% html_nodes("table")

data_body <- results[1] %>% html_nodes("tbody")
rows <- data_body %>% html_nodes("tr")

clean_rows_text <- str_replace_all(rows_text,"[7000100000000000000]", "")

clean_rows_text <- str_replace_all(clean_rows_text, "\n\n", ":")

clean_rows_text <- str_replace_all(clean_rows_text, "\n", "")
```

Desired output is:
`[3] "2:2: Texas:28,,845:25,46,5:4.4%:36:55,32:9,23:698,53:8.68%`"

From this point, I can handle the rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
data <- "2♠2:2♠2: Texas:28,,845:25,46,5:4.4%:36♠36:55,32:9,23:698,53:8.68%*"  
gsub("♠.+?(?=:)", "", data, perl=T)
```

Comment: It should, but didn't! Returns same result.

Comment: can you try adding `perl=T` to the gsub statement?

Comment: Thank you I have figured it out.